# Make a signal switch the action of another signal

Tags: c, signals, libc

I am working in C language. I am trying to catch and process two different signals:

- INT: when this signal is caught, *action1* or *action2* is triggered
- QUIT: when this signal is caught, the INT signal action is switched (*action1*->*action2* or *action2*->*action1*)

Default INT signal action is set to *action1*.

In my code,*switchaction* function is well triggered by QUIT signal, but has no effect on INT signal action :s

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);
sighandler_t prev_handler;

void action1(int n){
  printf("First message\n");
}
void action2(int n){
  printf("Second message\n");
}

void switchaction(int n){
  printf("Switch action\n");
  prev_handler=action2;
}

int main() {
  prev_handler = action1;
  printf("PID: %d\n", getpid());
  prev_handler= signal(SIGINT,prev_handler);
  signal(SIGQUIT,switchaction);

  travail(); //This function never ends
}
```

Would you have any idea of what is wrong in my code ?

Thanks,

Yann

Comment: BTW, you are not working in C,  but in C and Posix (or C and Linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syscall

```
prev_handler= signal(SIGINT,prev_handler);
```

is setting the signal handler to the value of `prev_handler` variable at the moment you are executing the `signal` syscall. Changing (after) the value of `prev_handler` does not change the handling of `SIGINT` signal. In other words, `signal` (and most C calls) have a [call by value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_by_value#Call_by_value) semantics. If you call `signal` once, the kernel keep the same handler (till you call `signal` again with the same signal number, or till you call [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) etc...).

Read carefully (assuming you are on Linux) the [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) man pages.

I would instead define

```
volatile sig_atomic_t howhandle;

void switchaction(int n __attribute__((unused))) {
    if (howhandle) 
       howhandle = 0;
    else 
       howhandle = 1;
}

void handleint (int n) {
    if (howhandle) action1(n); else action2(n);
}
```

and install just

```
signal(SIGINT, handleint);
signal(SIGQUIT, switchaction);
```

Also, notice that **calling `printf` inside a handler is incorrect** (because `printf` is *not* an async-signal-safe function, but you call it in `action1`, called by `handleint`...). Read again [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

You should have some other `volatile sig_atomic_t` variables and test (and clear them) at appropriate places inside your `travail` working function, but set them only in your signal handlers. Setting a `volatile sig_atomic_t` variable is pretty much the only thing you can do reliably inside a signal handler.

If you accept Linux specific solutions learn more about [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) (and use also [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)...). Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).